gcloud storage rsync patching all files every time when syncing GitHub repository
I am using Cloud Build to keep the files of a Google Cloud Storage bucket in sync with a GitHub repository.
My Google Cloud Build config yaml contains a step that executes this:
gcloud storage rsync ./ "gs://${_BUCKET_NAME}" --checksums-only --delete-unmatched-destination-objects -J -R

Yet I'm still seeing patching logs for each file each time I run the build.

It seems that when the command checksums-only was run, it indicates that gcloud storage rsync to compare files based on checksums, which can lead to patching logs being displayed even if the files have not changed.
You can consider removing the checksums-only flag from the gloucd storage rsync command to improve the synchronization process.

Without checksums-only, the modification dates would be used for comparison, which would lead to a full replacement every time.
